# How to get rid of search bar on home screen in 6.0

Tags: google-now, 6.0-marshmallow

I have already tried options mentioned in many other answers here/ posts online. I have a nexus 5
disable google now: option is disabled
use custom launcher: shows even in Nova launcher!

Edit: here is what I tried:

https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-remove-the-google-search-bar-from-your-android-homescreen

it doesn't work because Google Search doesn't appear in the list of installed apps in marshmallow

Comment: This is because Nova by default displays the search bar. You can remove it by long tapping on it and dragging it over the cross that appears at the top of the screen.

Comment: "*I have already tried options mentioned in many other answers here/ posts online.*" -- consider linking or explaining all of them here. This helps us to avoid suggesting solutions which didn't work for you.

Comment: @Firelord I tried to disable Google Now, but the option is disabled in marshmallow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the Google Search bar by installing an application [Xposed GEL Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.theknut.xposedgelsettings&hl=en_GB).

Open XGELS > Google Search Bar > Hide

**Please note:** This application requires ROOT and Xposed Framework.

Comment: looks like the only option for now